# What's the most optimal algorithm for a negative positive addition to an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, coding-style

Good evening. I had a coding interview on Codesignal with the question below, and I got just 14/20 with the test cases. How will you solve it please.

Given an array of nums, add positive and negative in succession and return the sum.

Example : given nums = {2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
Answer = 2-3+4-5+7 = 5.

What's the fastest algorithm for this?

I tried to use a two for loops and input -ve with i+1 for the second loop, but that's just brute force and terribly slow

Comment: Can you share your approach? Is it nested loops or 2 loops one by one?

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward with an O(n) approach which is the fastest possible. See https://onecompiler.com/java/3yr5vdw3a

Comment: I used the first for loop i as +ve integers, then i + 1 was multiplied by -1 for the second loop. Then I summed the results

Comment: Can you share some snippet for me to judge the time complexity? Are you also sure you shared the complete problem statement? These pointers are needed to take a better guess for your 14/20 issue.

Comment: You are giving two problems: (1) only passed 14/20 test cases; (2) it is too slow. Please focus on one problem only, and provide the code you have used to get that problem (so we can reproduce it).

Comment: "that's just brute force": this problem unavoidably takes exhaustive processing of the values, what you call "brute force".

Comment: Your question is missing details as well as your source code.

Comment: problem with separating into two for loop is that you might get overflow that you could avoid if you only make one loop.

Comment: @AloisChristen: if the values are signed, there is nothing you can affirm about this.

Comment: I don't believe that the running time should be incriminated. My bet is that you did not handle correctly the even or the odd case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust True in the general case. I'd still argue the problem state "in succession". Maybe there are test cases that are intended to fail if you don't do it in succession, but this is borderline bad faith xD

Comment: @AloisChristen: bordeline bad faith accepted :-) But if I am right, 2's complement arithmetic has the nice property that summations can be done in any order and always give the same result *despite intermediate overflow*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to avoid an exhaustive accumulation of the values, but this is terribly... fast. There is no need and no way to accelerate, besides unrolling the loop (which will probably have little effect) and parallelizing (out of the scope of the question).

IMO, the most reasonable way is with

```
int sum= 0; int i;
for (i= 0; i + 1 < n; i+= 2)
{
  sum+= num[i] - num[i+1];
}
if (i < n)
{
  sum+= num[i];
}
```

---

If the data is int32, positive, and the processor 64 bits, a nasty hack would be to load two values at a time as 64 bits and accumulate this way. In the end, you split back to 32 bits and perform the final subtraction. But again, I doubt the this will yield a significant speedup.